# move wordpress on digitalocean to another cloud server on aliyun failed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

I try to move my wordpress on digitalocean server to another cloud server on aliyun, On digitalocean server, it is LAMP, On aliyun server, it is LNMP.

First, I install nginx, php, mysql on my aliyun server, all succeed.
my nginx conf:

[image]

Then, I tar wordpress on digitalserver, and scp it to aliyun server and untar it. I also use:

```
mysqldump -u root -p wordpress > wordpress.sql
```

command to backup wordpress database on digitalocean server, and scp wordpress.sql to aliyun server, and On my aliyun server, I create database wordpress and source wordpress.sql.

I modify table wp-options, update siteurl and home to my aliyun server ip.

When I visit ip in browser, it just display blank pages, mysql log and nginx log don't have any error, so I was confused. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) White screens are PHP errors. Try Debug and see what PHP errors you are getting.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Change the DISPLAY line to true, i.e.

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to log and dump them to the browser.

2) Look in the aliyun server logs for information on errors

3) Reupload all core Wordpress files and folders

4) Check permissions: [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: It does not work, I add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);` in wp-content there is no debug.log file and browser is blank page..

Comment: Test Nginx, etc, with a simple static webpage in root. If that works, replace all core Wordpress files and folders by FTP.

Comment: I ever tried that I modified index.php under wordpress dir, add a line `phpinfo();`, and It can display phpinfo on the website..    what is the difference between FTP and scp ?

Comment: You need to fix Nginx first; then work on WordPress.

Comment: I will try. Thank you for your reply.